# pass database generated multiple checkbox values to <input type="text"> using javascript and query database

Tags: javascript, database, text, checkbox

```
print "<Font face=\"calibri, Arial\"><table id=\"rnatable\" border=2px width=100%>";
print "<th></th>";
print "<th>a</th>";
print "<th>b</th>";
print "<th>c</th>";
print "<th>d</th>";
print "<th>e</th>";
print "<th>f</th>";
print "<th>g</th>";



while($array = mysql_fetch_array($sql_query))
{
$id=$array['a'];
print "<tr id=\"newtr\">";
print "<td><input id=\"check\" type=\"checkbox\" name=\"keyword[]\" value=\"$id\" ></td>";
print "<td>".$array['a']."</td>";
print "<td>".$array['b']."</td>";
print "<td>".$array['c']."</td>";
print "<td>".$array['d']."</td>";
print "<td>".$array['e']."</td>";
print "<td>".$array['f']."</td>";

print "<td>
<a href=\"http://localhost/rnasearch/retrieve.php?a=$id\">bla</a>
</td></tr></font>";

}

print "</table>";
}
```

this is part of a php searchengine script that i wrote to retrieve data from a database and as you can see the last column that is g contains a link which when clicked takes the user to the second php script which retrieves additional information of that entry, but this is done for only single entries so as you can see i introduced checkboxes so that the user can check any number of checkboxes and retrieve information as per their wish

now to do this i created a

```
    <div id="floatMenu"> 
<ul class="menu1"> 
<center><li><form name="senddata" method="POST" action="http://localhost/retrieve.php" style="display:inline;"><input id="fasta" type="text" class="multitext"><input name="Fasta" type="Submit" value="Retrieve Fasta"></form>
```

this is a css floating menu....so far so good....everything went fine....
after this i had to write a javascript to do this and i've been stuck there searching forums for the last 4 days!

this is the javascript i found from somewhere which came close to doing wht i wanted it to do

```
    window.onload = function () { 
var cb = document.getElementById('check');
var fasta = document.getElementById('fasta');
cb.onclick = function () {fasta.value = cb.value + ","; 
};};
```

this script only sends the value of the first checkbox in the table, the others are not found by it, mind you its not the first checkbox selected its the first checkbox that is present in the table

how can i resolve this problem so that even if i have n number of checkboxes in my table, if the user chooses to do so they can retrieve n number of information....please help i've almost lost hope in this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs are meant to be unique in one HTML Document. So you can't use them to retrieve many of them with the same Id. You may have to modify your PHP and JS like this:

```
$i=0;
while($array = mysql_fetch_array($sql_query))

{
$id=$array['a'];
print "<tr id=\"newtr\">";
print "<td><input id=\"check_$i\" type=\"checkbox\" name=\"keyword[]\" value=\"$id\" ></td>";
print "<td>".$array['a']."</td>";
print "<td>".$array['b']."</td>";
print "<td>".$array['c']."</td>";
print "<td>".$array['d']."</td>";
print "<td>".$array['e']."</td>";
print "<td>".$array['f']."</td>";

print "<td>
<a href=\"http://localhost/rnasearch/retrieve.php?a=$id\">bla</a>
</td></tr>";
$i++;
}

print "</table>";
}
```

And

```
    window.onload = function () { 
    var cb = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var fasta = document.getElementById('fasta');
    for (i=0;i<cb.length;++i)
    {
      if ( cb[i].type === 'checkbox' && cb[i].name === 'keyword[]')
          cb[i].onclick = function (e) {
            var str = e.target.value + ","
            if(e.target.checked)
                fasta.value += str;
            else
            {
                var ind = fasta.value.indexOf(str);
                fasta.value = fasta.value.substr(0, ind) + fasta.value.substr(ind+str.length,fasta.value.length);
            }
    }
};};
```

You can find a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZfmNw/1/

Comment: I'm sorry but this javascript did not work, i would really like to know why the solution to this simple task is so hard to find as most javascripts i tried till now were unable to accomplish this simple task

Comment: Try for (var i=0;i<cb.length;++i) guess I was missing that one.

Comment: i had declared the variable the first time, and you had missed some braces i think, yet it didnt work, I'm yet to understand why the logic isn't holding with the program itself bcoz the logic is very correct.

Comment: i just corrected it again. it works perfectly for me. you may should consider to put your checkboxes within the form instead of this hacking, so you don't need to worry about this. you may also should consider what is going to happen if a checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: would this being a .php file have anything to do with the javascript not working for me?

Comment: It should also work with a PHP file if you included the script properly: see http://jsfiddle.net/ZfmNw/

Comment: thank you so much!!!!!! that finally worked! can you please incorporate the if checked condition there as well...i really don't want to touch this script right now...i tried putting in the the if(cb[i].checked) clause and immediately it stopped working....so i better leave it alone.